# WSO2 api manager 200 - Delegating authentication

Tags: wso2, api-manager

Does anyone knows how to perform authentication in backend system, below Api Manager ?

Trying to implement own custom user store, but after place the builded jar in folder "repository/components/dropins", nothing vas loaded at product starting and in the carbon console interface, custom userstore doesn't appear...

Version of apim: WSO2 APIM 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 APIM 2.0.0 is an osgi framework. When you build an osgi bundle and place it on "repository/components/dropins" it will be visible from the osgi console.
Find the reason why your bundle is not starting using these steps:

1. Start the osgi console do "$ sh wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole"
2. Search for your bundle type 'osgi> ss *bundle-name*' and note the id
3. Try to start your bundle with 'osgi> start *id*' and the reason with it doesn't start will be displayed.

If the bundle is not displayed in the list, it may be that your jar is not a valid osgi or is created on a different osgi version. You could also try to install the bundle manually on the osgi console using 'osgi> install file:/path/to/your/bundle.jar'

More documentation can be found here https://wso2.com/library/articles/getting-started-wso2-carbon/

I hope that helps with your debugging.